# FATAL ERROR: wasm code commit Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Пытаюсь запустить проект React.js на Mac c процессором M1, но выдает ошибку о нехватке памяти.
Пробовал запустить этот проект на windows и там все работает нормально. Версии nodejs совпадают.

Ошибка происходит только при запуске сервера разработки, то есть при запуске скрипта start, остальные скрипты работают нормально.

Вот package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "name",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
        "@testing-library/dom": "^7.29.4",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
        "@types/node": "^12.19.15",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
        "@vkontakte/icons": "^1.74.0",
        "@vkontakte/vk-bridge": "^2.4.0",
        "@vkontakte/vkjs": "^0.20.0",
        "@vkontakte/vkui": "^4.0.8",
        "eruda": "^2.4.1",
        "eruda-code": "^2.0.0",
        "eruda-dom": "^2.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "typescript": "^4.1.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "cross-env PORT=10888 HTTPS=true BROWSER=none react-app-rewired start",
        "build": "react-app-rewired build",
        "deploy": "vk-miniapps-deploy",
        "ontunnel": "vk-tunnel --insecure=1 --http-protocol=https --ws-protocol=wss --host=localhost --port=10888",
        "test": "react-app-rewired test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vkontakte/vk-miniapps-deploy": "^0.0.22",
        "@vkontakte/vk-tunnel": "^0.0.15",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "react-app-rewire-alias": "^0.1.9",
        "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8"
      }
    }
```

Текст ошибки:

```
/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node /Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js run start
yarn run v1.22.10
$ cross-env PORT=10888 HTTPS=true BROWSER=none react-app-rewired start
The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at https://192.168.1.65/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/mrkeksz/WebstormProjects/vkma-dating/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...


<--- Last few GCs --->

[94207:0x130008000]     1077 ms: Scavenge 78.9 (105.0) -> 69.3 (105.0) MB, 1.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.996, current mu = 0.996) allocation failure 
[94207:0x130008000]     1221 ms: Scavenge 87.2 (106.8) -> 76.2 (108.3) MB, 1.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.996, current mu = 0.996) allocation failure 
[94207:0x130008000]     1301 ms: Scavenge 90.5 (111.7) -> 82.2 (115.7) MB, 1.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.996, current mu = 0.996) task 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: wasm code commit Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: 0x10471a9d8 node::Abort() [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 2: 0x10471ab58 node::errors::TryCatchScope::~TryCatchScope() [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 3: 0x104834384 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 4: 0x104834318 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 5: 0x104dc9cdc v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeAllocator::AllocateForCodeInRegion(v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule*, unsigned long, v8::base::AddressRegion, v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeAllocator::OptionalLock const&) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 6: 0x104dca970 v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule::CreateEmptyJumpTableInRegion(int, v8::base::AddressRegion, v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeAllocator::OptionalLock const&) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 7: 0x104dc9638 v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule::AddCodeSpace(v8::base::AddressRegion, v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeAllocator::OptionalLock const&) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 8: 0x104dca780 v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule::NativeModule(v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, v8::internal::VirtualMemory, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::Counters>, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule>*) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 9: 0x104dcccf4 v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeManager::NewNativeModule(v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine*, v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, unsigned long, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
10: 0x104dd8808 v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine::NewNativeModule(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>, unsigned long) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
11: 0x104da7b54 v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::CreateNativeModule(std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>, unsigned long) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
12: 0x104da7d1c v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::GetOrCreateNativeModule(std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>, unsigned long) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
13: 0x104db0380 v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::PrepareAndStartCompile::RunInForeground(v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob*) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
14: 0x104db014c v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::CompileTask::RunInternal() [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
15: 0x104777c08 node::PerIsolatePlatformData::RunForegroundTask(std::__1::unique_ptr<v8::Task, std::__1::default_delete<v8::Task> >) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
16: 0x1047768a0 node::PerIsolatePlatformData::FlushForegroundTasksInternal() [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
17: 0x104f2dc20 uv__async_io [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
18: 0x104f3f7e0 uv__io_poll [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
19: 0x104f2e0b0 uv_run [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
20: 0x104752f40 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
21: 0x1046f37d0 node::Start(int, char**) [/Users/mrkeksz/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
22: 0x1a32cdf34 start [/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib]
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Пробовал запускать node с опцией --max-old-space-size=8192, но ничего не меняется

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38560292

Comment: @nörbörnën Я пробовал запускать с этими опциями: --max-old-space-size=8192 --optimize-for-size --max_old_space_size=8192 --optimize_for_size

Ничего не меняется